# Show view controller in other controller on center

Tags: objective-c, view, controller

In my project, there is three controller.

```
1)MainController
2)AViewController
3)BViewController.
```

My problem is that, i want to show AViewController  on Centre of MainController.
when Button of AViewController is clicked, then BViewController is set on centre of MainController.
Please help, i am new in Xcode, objective c.

Answer (score 0):

You can add AViewController and BViewController as child view controllers.

Here's an example for adding AViewController as a child view controller on MainController:

```
[myMainController addChildViewController:myAViewController];
[myMainController.view addSubview:myAViewController.view];
[myAViewController didMoveToParentViewController:myMainController];
```

You can also find more information about creating custom Container View Controllers [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html)

Comment: i want to add AViewController on centre of MainViewController

Comment: The example above does that. You can also adjust the size and positioning for AViewController by setting a new CGRect on AViewController's view.

Comment: when i click button of AViewController (AViewController added in MainViewController) it give error.